# ElasticNet & cv.glmnet predicts wrong outcome

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, cross-validation, glmnet

I am running a binary ElasticNet regression cross-validated for 620 000 observations and 21 variables using cv.glmnet in R.

```
A tibble: 62,905 x 13
         V1      V2      V3     V4    V5    V6    V7    V8   V9    V10   V11        V12    V13
       <dbl>    <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <fct>
 1     -37.8      0     165.   269.  21.9  0.607  84.0   0    65.1  290. 4.36      8        0
 2     -68.1      0     303.   168.  44.5  1.41   89.9   0    46.6  296. 0.692     34.7     0
 3     -54.3      0     332.   168.  44.5  1.41   89.9   0    46.6  296. 0.692     35.8     1
 4    -108.       0     338.   168.  44.5  1.41   89.9   0    46.6  296. 0.692     30.3     0
 5     -60.3      0     374.   171.  35.7  2.30   88.9   0.3  51.7  295. 4.01      29.6     1
 6     -82.8      0     48.2   133.  18.4  0.210  84.9   0    65.1  289. 1.35      18.7     0
 7     -99.6      0     299.   219.  42.6  2.09   90.8   0    34.2  297. 1.42       7       1
 8     -98.1      0     116.   153.  44.7  0.988  89.0   0    41.3  298. 0.235     32.6     0
```

When the cv.glment is done, I predict my new outcome of `y`. This is now 10-fold higher than my actual observations. Why do I end up with 10 times higher predicted `y`?
Here is my code:

```
set.seed(123)
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
library(glmnet)
library(ROCR)
training.samples <- data$V1 %>% createDataPartition(p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train <- data[training.samples, ]
test <- data[-training.samples, ]
x.train <- data.frame(train[, names(train) != "V1"])
x.train <- data.matrix(x.train)
y.train <- train$fire
x.test <- data.frame(test[, names(test) != "V1"])
x.test <- data.matrix(x.test)
y.test <- test$fire
> model <- cv.glmnet(x.train, y.train, type.measure = c("auc"), alpha = i/10, family = "binomial", parallel = TRUE)
> predicted1 <- predict(model, s = "lambda.min", newx = x.test)
> View(predicted1)
```

And here are two histograms of my `y.test` outcome. Sidenote: I do have some 100 `1` in my `y.test` observations but a lot more `0`.

[image: OBSERVED Y.TEST][image: PREDICTED Y.TEST]

What is going wrong in the cross-validation?

EDIT: After @smiling4ever's comment, I succeeded. Hence, I added `type = "response"`
`predicted1 <- predict(model, s = "lambda.min", newx = x.test, type = "response")`

Comment: Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @BappaDas, I am well aware of this. I have put everything in but the dataset as it, in my opinion, is of no use. I inform about the test, logistic, ergo binary outcome (0 or 1) and the predicted is everything between 0 and 15. I state my problem and provide a code. What else is missing?

Comment: Without the dataset, how can anyone reproduce what you are claiming?

Comment: @BappaDas, the 620 000 observation and 21 variables dataset?

Comment: If you want to get probabilities then use type="response"predicted1 <- predict(model, s = "lambda.min", newx = x.test, type= "response")

Comment: @smiling4ever thank you! That helped me big time - I'm grateful.